# Access 2013 refer to a combobox's own tag in its rowsource

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have some comboboxes on a form and I'd like each box's `RowSource` to refer to the tag I set. The tag will filter the appropriate dropdown options from a table.

```
SELECT DropdownNames
FROM Table
WHERE DropdownCategory=[Screen].[ActiveForm]![Me].[Tag]
```

What is the correct syntax? Is using the tag the best way to do this or is there a better property for this purpose?

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this directly inside RowSource property. You could do it with VBA in a loop inside the Form_Load event that goes thru all your combobox controls with Tag<>"". The syntax would need to be changed to `WHERE DropdownCategory=""" & ctl.Tag & """"` - given that ctl is defined in your loop.

Comment: @dbmitch Ah, somehow I'm not surprised Access doesn't have an easy way to do this in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's example of what I suggested.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Const DROPDOWN_SQL  As String = "SELECT DropdownNames FROM Table WHERE DropdownCategory = "
    Const DOUBLE_QUOTES As String = """"

    Dim ctl             As Control
    Dim strRowsource    As String

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        With ctl
            ' Only look at Tagged Combo Boxes
            If (.ControlType = acComboBox) And (.Tag <> "") Then
                ' Set Dropdown Row Source
                strRowsource = DROPDOWN_SQL & DOUBLE_QUOTES & .Tag & DOUBLE_QUOTES
                .RowSource = strRowsource
            End If
        End With
    Next

    Set ctl = Nothing
End Sub
```